# Cumulative Daily Volume Measure in Power BI not working as expected

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Hi I am trying to check how many product have been delivered day on day basis in cumulative order i.e. my graph would be in upward trend. So if on day 1 I have delivered 50 product and on day 2 I have delivered 31 product so on day 2 it should say 81 product.

I have created below measure for above requirement however for every new month value adds the previous month final value i.e. if suppose in Year 2023-10 I have delivered 10000 product and on 1st Nov, I delivered 10 product then on day1 of Year 2023-11 it will show 10011 which is incorrect. This Does not work in sequence so the first month that I select in filter works correctly however if I add another month then it is causing the issue.

```
New Daily Volume = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(product[product_delivered]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('product'),
        'product'[product_deliver_date] <= MAX('product'[product_deliver_date])
    )
)
```

Below chart shows Incorrect chart in the Power BI using above Measure formula.
[image: Incorrect chart my data is showing in the Power BI]

However the correct representation would be below chart
[image: Correct Chart]

Raw Data

| product_deliver_date | updated_month | product_delivered | dayofthemonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/1/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 1 |
| 11/1/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 1 |
| 11/2/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 2 |
| 11/2/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 2 |
| 11/2/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 2 |
| 11/2/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 2 |
| 10/3/2023 | 2023-10 | 1 | 3 |
| 10/3/2023 | 2023-10 | 1 | 3 |
| 11/3/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 3 |
| 11/3/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 3 |
| 11/3/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 3 |
| 11/4/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 4 |
| 11/4/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 4 |
| 11/4/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 4 |
| 11/4/2023 | 2023-11 | 1 | 4 |
| 10/4/2023 | 2023-10 | 1 | 4 |
| 10/4/2023 | 2023-10 | 1 | 4 |
| 10/4/2023 | 2023-10 | 1 | 4 |
| 11/3/2023 | 2023-10 | 1 | 3 |

Below image represent the number how it should be represent and how it is represented(Refer 2023-11(Incorrect)) column which is incorrect however I want data to be represented as column 2023-10(Correct) , 2023-11(Correct)

[image]

Can someone help me with this please? I am just starting to learn Power BI so kindly let me know how to resolve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a separate Date table? (You should.) Don't take my word for it. Look at daxpatterns[dot]com.
Given a date dimension (dimDate), these measures work:

Qty Delivered = SUM('FactDelivery'[product_delivered])

RT Delivered = Delivered = CALCULATE( [Qty Delivered],
                    FILTER( ALL('DimDate'[Date]),
                            'DimDate'[Date]<=MAX('DimDate'[Date])
                    )
)

Comment: No I don't have separate date table and given the structure and size of the data that I am working on creating a new table would start giving me space issue.

Comment: ?? How do you mean? You can bash out a Calendar table with some simple DAX:
ADDCOLUMNS(
CALENDAR(
  MINX('FactDelivery'[Date]),MAXX('FactDelivery'[Date])
),
"Year",YEAR([Date]),
"MonthNo",MONTH([Date]),
"Month", FORMAT([Date],"MMM")
)
then just join. (Date tables, relatively speaking, are TINY.)

Comment: It's more efficient (and makes your model smaller) if you have ONE Date table instead of a separate one that PowerBI builds under the covers for each date column in your model.